# Transform a function into template build

Tags: php, function

I'm starting in the world of PHP. Ok, right in the point, i want to build a function that print a HTML code (like a template).

Example:

```
function template($image, $name){
  echo '<figure>
           <img src="'.$image.'" />
           <figcaption>'.$name.'</figcaption>
        </figure>';
}
```

I've searched for template engine (think that is the name) and i found one called Twig.

But okay, what is the better way to buildy "templates" in PHP?

Thank you!